# Transaction not succefully started

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, transactions

I'm tryin' to pass date parametters to my application but i have some difficults
My DAO looks like this:

```
@Override
public List <Object[]>getMontantParVehicule(Date d1,Date d2) {

    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Stat HQL");
    SQLQuery q=session.createSQLQuery("select IMMAT,SUM(PRIX) as  COUT,SUM(QUANTITE) as QUANTITE,COUNT(IMMAT) as nbre from BON_ESSENCE where DATE_BON between   :debut and :fin  GROUP BY IMMAT ");
  //  Query q =session.createQuery("select immat,sum(prix) as mnt from BonEssence group    by immat  ");
    q.setParameter("debut",d1  );
    q.setParameter("fin",d2  );
return q.list();
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }finally{

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }


}
```

and

```
private Date d1;
private Date d2;
public Date getD1() {
    return d1;
}
public void setD1(Date d1) {
    this.d1 = d1;
}
public Date getD2() {
    return d2;
}
public void setD2(Date d2) {
    this.d2 = d2;
}
public List<Object[]> getMontantParVehiculeTotal(){
    return essenceService.getMontantParVehicule(d1, d2);
    }
```

My xhtml pages look like:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid2">

                <h:outputLabel value=" debut: *" for="txt_d1" />
                 <p:calendar locale="fr" value="#{bonEssenceBean.d1}" id="txt_d1" datePattern="dd/yyyy/MM" required="true" ></p:calendar>

                <h:outputLabel value=" Fin: *" for="txt_d2" />
                 <p:calendar locale="fr" value="#{bonEssenceBean.d2}" id="txt_d2" datePattern="dd/yyyy/MM" required="true" ></p:calendar>


             <p:button id="btn_add" value="Enregistrer"
                outcome="DetailBon" >
                <f:param name="d1" value="#{bonEssenceBean.d1}"></f:param>
                <f:param name="d2" value="#{bonEssenceBean.d2}"></f:param>
                </p:button>

        </h:panelGrid>
```

and

```
<ui:composition template="/Views/Template/common.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="Edition">
    <h:form id="form">

    </h:form>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="Consultation">
  <h:form id="form2">
  <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     -->

  <p:dataTable id="statTable" var="item" value="#{bonEssenceBean.montantParVehiculeTotal}"  widgetVar="statTable" sortMode="single" rows="5" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,15,25">    
  <f:facet name="header">
          <p:outputPanel>  
               <h:outputText value="Search:" style="Height:30px"/>  
               <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()"  style="width:150px" />  
          </p:outputPanel>  

       </f:facet>
        <p:column  headerText="Vehicule"   > 

            <h:outputText value="#{item[0]}" />

        </p:column>  

        <p:column  headerText="COUT">  
            <h:outputText value="#{item[1]}" />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column  headerText="QUANTITE">  
            <h:outputText value="#{item[2]}" />  
        </p:column> 
         <p:column  headerText="Nombre de bon">  
            <h:outputText value="#{item[3]}" />  

        </p:column>



    </p:dataTable>



  </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

I think  it is because my parametters are not correctly passed to the SQL request. could someone help me please?

Comment: may be show db structure or hibernate mapping for this entity

Comment: i'm using hbernate annotation.If i put static parameters, it perfectly works perhaps _private Date d1=new Date(); private Date d2=new Date();__ will work

Comment: What is the declaration/annotation of your DAO/managed bean?

Comment: problem is not about annotation but about passing  parameters because in url, i can see this;**..../DetailBon.jsf?d1=null&d2=null** parameters don't take effect.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, if everything is in one form (and without template).

Comment: I have removed template since you told me.But how could I pass parameters if I use only one form?

Answer (score 1):

### Data access layer

In case of an exception (invalid HQL, possibly based on `null` filter arguments) you are rolling back the transaction, but later you are **always** committing the transaction in a `finally` block. This probably creates another exception, and the 1st one is lost.

Pseudo code:

```
try {
  session.beginTransaction();
  // HQL
  session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  session.getTransaction().rollback();
  throw e;
}
```

### Presentation access layer

This `enterDate.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Date 1" for="date1" />
        <h:inputText value="#{dateModel.date1}" id="date1">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
        </h:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="Date 2" for="date2" />
        <p:calendar locale="de" value="#{dateModel.date2}" id="date2"
            required="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="button1" value="Show" action="showDate" />
</h:form>
```

together with `showDate.xhtml`

```
<h:outputText value="#{dateModel.date1}" />
<br />
<h:outputText value="#{dateModel.date2}" />
```

using this model

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dateModel")
@SessionScoped
public class DateModel {
    private Date date1 = new Date();
    private Date date2 = new Date();

    public Date getDate1() {
        return this.date1;
    }

    public void setDate1(Date _date1) {
        this.date1 = _date1;
        System.out.println("date1: " + this.date1);
    }

    public Date getDate2() {
        return this.date2;
    }

    public void setDate2(Date _date2) {
        this.date2 = _date2;
        System.out.println("date2: " + this.date2);
    }
}
```

shows the dates.

Comment: the URL shows that _http://localhost:8080/AMS/Views/Carburant/DetailBon.jsf?d1=null&d2=null_ it means d1 and d2 didn't take parameters. is there other way to pass parameters to the bean? this one is in **primeface user guide** maybe i used with mistake

Comment: In your template there are two forms. So try to do it in one form and without a template first.

Comment: Please try `<p:commandButton id="btn_add" value="Enregistrer" action="DetailBon" />`. If this does not work, *add* the current state of your .xhtml to the question.

Comment: @user2550268 I have updated the answer. Which annotations do you have on your managed bean?

Comment: _@Component
@Scope
public class BonEssenceBean {_ and _@Autowired
 public void setEssenceService(BonEssenceService essenceService) {
  this.essenceService = essenceService;
 }_ I'm truing your answer now thank you

Comment: I got same result when i chage date._Tue Aug 13 17:35:11 WEST 2013 
Tue Aug 13 17:35:11 WEST 2013_